# Sending an email from your app with an image attached in Swift

Tags: swift, image, email, messageui

I've tried a lot of tutorials on sending emails in your app but none of the ones I've seen show how to send an image with it. I'm recovering an image from .WriteToFile, This image is set to a UIImageView. How should I send an email with my picture?

Niall

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to add an `attachmentData` to your mail, encoding your image
in an NSData. This is an example that show you how to send an email with
your image. I'm suppose that you have a `UIViewController` where you can put the function `sendMail`.

```
import MessageUI
class MyViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
{
  // .... your stuff

  func sendMail(imageView: UIImageView) {
    if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
      let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
      mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
      mail.setCcRecipients(["yyyy@xxx.com"])
      mail.setSubject("Your messagge")
      mail.setMessageBody("Message body", isHTML: false)
      let imageData: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image)!
      mail.addAttachmentData(imageData, mimeType: "image/png", fileName: "imageName.png")
      self.presentViewController(mail, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
  } 

}
```

In order to dismiss the VC, include the following method in your `ViewController`:

```
func mailComposeController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController,
    didFinishWithResult result: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?) {
        controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

The documentation for this method is reported in [MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate_protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate/mailComposeController:didFinishWithResult:error:).

Comment: How should I dismiss the Mail Form when Cancel is pressed? Screen shot: https://postimg.org/image/6pz5yv5lj/

Comment: Thanks Adda_25 this helped a lot.