# Sharesheet doesn't attach file in mail app (swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, email, pdf, share

I need to share a file (it can be pdf, xlsx or an image) using a Sharesheet. It works on whatsapp or other apps but when I select "mail" only opens mail app but without any attachment. Here is my code:

```
let myURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: fileURLString)
let activityItems: [AnyObject] = [myURL as AnyObject]
let activityViewController: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItems, applicationActivities: nil)
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView=self.view
self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

(I am running it in the main thread from an asynchronous task)

Comment: You can use `MFMailComposeViewController ` instead of `UIActivityViewController`, please check this out -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/38376049/7512091

Comment: You are missing this line, you must provide it into work on iPad.
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect=...
Also, could you print the description of myURL and share it here?

Comment: You can add the file as NSData, that works for standard iOS Mail app, but it doesn't for another apps.